# CSS Cannot set table width to be dynamic with screen width

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am having an issue with my CSS, It is by far something i am not good at but i cant seem to solve an issue where my Table will not display based on screen width. It used to be static but since changing the values to % of screen it has not made any visual changes to my Table. (UPDATED BASED ON ANSWERS/COMMENTS)

HTML / PHP

```
//Table Titles row
echo "<div class='tablediv' style='width:100%; border: 5px solid black'><table name ='ipv4' class='tableparent'><td class='tabled' width='100%'>IP Address</td><td class='table'>Subnet</td><td class='table'>PC Name</td><td class='table'>Owner</td><td class='table'>Customer</td><td class='table'>Customer Site</td></tr>";

//loops through search results and echo table

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($view)){

    $id = $row['companyId'];
    $company = $customers[$id];

    echo "<tr><td class='tabled'>". $row['ip']."</td><td class='table'>". $row['Subnet']."</td><td class='table'>".$row['hostName']."</td><td class='table'>". $row['owner']."</td><td class='table'>". $company ."</td><td class='table'>".$row['siteName']."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo"</table></div>";
```

CSS

```css
.table
{
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  padding:10px;
  width:12%;
  overflow:hidden;  
}

.tabled
{
  top:500px;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  width:40%;
  overflow: hidden;     
}   

.tableparent
{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width: 95%;
  text-align: left;
  padding:15px;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.tablediv
{
  position:absolute;
  width: 95%;
  top:70px;
}
```

Currently this displays the table looking like this

[image: updated image of table]

Comment: Add inline css of width as 100% to table also. Also to confirm the width, please add border to both div and table, so you can confirm the width.

Comment: The table has a border, I Added a 5px solid black border to the tablediv class, it did not appear. after deleting the tablediv class, nothing appeared to have changed visually. Check the comment i posted to Haresh Vidja's comment for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add width="100%" in table tag, it will set full width as parent div width

```
echo "<div class='tablediv' style='width:100%'><table width='100%' name ='ipv4' class='tableparent'><td class='tabled'>IP Address</td><td class='table'>Subnet</td><td class='table'>PC Name</td><td class='table'>Owner</td><td class='table'>Customer</td><td class='table'>Customer Site</td></tr>";
```

Comment: I added in the `width='100%'` still noting, even after i deleted the tablediv it has made no effect! Would the issue be that the html being echo'd is not on my main HTML page. Therefore the div may not be valid as it could be echoing outside the body. Do you know if this could be the case, or at least how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, The page was POST'ed to by ajax. I then found that the result's div of the search was accidentally surrounded by another div, limiting its width. Thanks for the help